# How can I get raw content of a file which is stored on hdfs with gzip compressed ?

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way that can read raw content of a file which is stored on hadoop hdfs byte by byte ?

Typically when I submit a streaming job with `-input` param that point to an `.gz` file (like `-input hdfs://host:port/path/to/gzipped/file.gz`).

My task received decompressed input line by line, this is **NOT** what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `FileSystem` with respective Hadoop configuration:

```
FileSystem.get(conf);
```

It has a method `open` which should in principle allow you to read raw data.